# Docker file for a Laravel 8 with React UI (Scaffolding)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, docker

I have create a Laravel Project & React Scaffolding, it means React as UI.
Before this project, i have use both Libraries as two different, for example App-frontend(React) and App-backend(Laravel).
But now i have create ***only one App*** and it will run on one Container. My Container what i have used before for the App-backend is this one;

```
FROM php:8.0.10-fpm-alpine
LABEL Maintainer="me" \
      Description="Docker container with Nginx 1.15 & PHP-FPM 7.4 based on Alpine Linux. Nginx Confg Ready for Laravel/Lumen"

      ENV BUILD_DEPS \
                cmake \
                autoconf \
                g++ \
                gcc \
                make \
                pcre-dev \
                gmp-dev  \
                zip \
                libzip-dev \
                imagemagick-dev 
                
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $BUILD_DEPS $PHPIZE_DEPS 

RUN set -ex && apk --no-cache add sudo

RUN apk --no-cache add nginx supervisor curl postgresql-dev libuv-dev openldap-dev ssmtp libxml2-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql pgsql  pdo_pgsql

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev


RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip 


      #Install Locales
  ENV MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS   musl-dev  gettext-dev libintl 
  ENV MUSL_LOCPATH /usr/share/i18n/locales/musl

  RUN apk add --no-cache \
      $MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS \
      && wget https://gitlab.com/rilian-la-te/musl-locales/-/archive/master/musl-locales-master.zip \
      && unzip musl-locales-master.zip \
        && cd musl-locales-master \
        && cmake -DLOCALE_PROFILE=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr . && make && make install \
        && cd .. && rm -r musl-locales-master

 

# Add Envsubst 
ENV TZ="Europe/Berlin" \
    RUNTIME_DEPS="libintl"
RUN apk add --update $RUNTIME_DEPS  \
    && apk add --virtual build_deps gettext   \
    && cp /usr/bin/envsubst /usr/local/bin/envsubs \
 # Add default timezone
    && apk add tzdata \
    && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime \
    && echo "${TZ}" > /etc/timezone 

# Configure nginx
COPY .deploy/nginx.conf /nginx.conf

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY .deploy/fpm-pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz_custom.conf
COPY .deploy/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel_custom.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY .deploy/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Configure ssmtp config
COPY .deploy/ssmtp.conf /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

# Configure Cron Job for Scheduler
#COPY .deploy/scheduler /var/www/html/scheduler 
#RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/scheduler 
COPY .deploy/crontab /etc/crontabs/root 
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/crontabs/root 


# Add application
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY src/. /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
RUN sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage/
RUN sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
# RUN php artisan cache:clear
# RUN php artisan config:cache && php artisan view:cache

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

Now i need help to add the Docker command for the React to run and copy in the src where it run. Can you help me please?

Comment: Taking two separate apps and combining them to run in one docker container seems very anti-docker. If they were already separate, just run them in separate containers.

Comment: As always, someone more knowledgeable is free to contradict me, but I've come to realize that using supervisor within a docker container is a bit of an antipattern. If I need more than one process to be running in the container, its usually a good argument that I need another container. They can be connected by a docker network and run the same exact way, but with better defined responsibilities and error, logging, etc.

Comment: For clarification; this is only one App, React is the UI in the Laravel Library. But there is still a npm command to run. In this case 2 different container will not work.

Comment: It can work. I've done it several times for this exact scenario. However if you are committed to the one container approach, you'll probably want to set up a supervisor job to start the node server.

Comment: Hello Brian, you right i have done it also before, but i do not use a node server, in Laravel i do not need it. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#react . There must be a simple solution for it, where i going to find out very soon i hope.

Comment: If you're using mix that's important information to put in your question. All react is not the same. Setting up docker for static, vs SSR, etc is not going to have the same answer.

Comment: Anyone here to help maybe?